# Qt5 "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"

Tags: macos, qt, compiler-construction, compilation, qt5

First of all, I know there are also others posts talking about this bug but mine is a bit different I think.

I've got a Qt project with this pro file :

```
QT       += core
QT       += network
QT       -= gui

TARGET = QDownloaderCLI

CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle


TEMPLATE ...
```

I tried with `CONFIG -= X86_64` but nothing change.

Searching on the web I discover something strange, I've got a .h file with a public slot with his implementation in a .cpp file :

```
public slots:
    void stateChanged(int state);
```

With this I've got the error message but if I comment `void stateChanged(int state);` in .h and .cpp it works.

How do I fix this ?

I also have warnings :

```
directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Qt//5.1.0/clang_64/qtbase/lib'
```

and

```
"This version of OS X is unsupported" [-W#warnings]
```

I also tried "Run qMake" but I've got warnings too :

```
No .qmake.cache is present. This significantly slows down qmake with this makespec.
Call 'cache()' in the top-level project file to rectify this problem.
```

I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.4 with Qt 5.1.0

Code of my .h file :

```
#ifndef DOWNLOADER_H
#define DOWNLOADER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
// In Qt 5 no more QHttp
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

class downloader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit downloader(QObject *parent = 0);
    void doDownload();

signals:

public slots:
    void stateChanged(int state);

private:
   QNetworkAccessManager *http;

};

#endif // DOWNLOADER_H
```

Comment: Do you use any third party library in your stateChanged function?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simply syntax error

Comment: @AndrewBarber The question is not about a syntax error.  Getting the linking/compiling flags to be correct for a Qt project on OS X is not trivial.  This is the first result I found when searching for this particular error in my attempt to build my complex Qt project on OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide your compile output so we can help you, right now you have only given us the warnings from the issue output.

I usally get this error when i have a reference error on OSX.
I.e when i have declared a function in my .h file and then haven't declared it.

have you tested moving the stateChanged function to be public instead of a slot?

what happens when you try to follow the function by rightclicking on the function in the .cpp file and choose follow symbol under cursor.

If the connection is wrong between the .cpp and .h file you will get an error there.
You can also try to declare the function in the .h file to test it.

The warning you are getting is a warning you always get and it shouldn't make the app not runnable. I get it everytime i run applications.

Please provide the compile output.

Regards /RK

Comment: When I declared it as public instead of public slot it compiles. And the only error message I get is  avertissement : directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Qt//5.1.0/clang_64/qtbase/lib'. And right click on the function in .cpp does nothing.

Comment: You compile output should look something like this `09:15:54: Starting: "C:\Qt\5.0.2\Tools\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/Qt/5.0.2/Tools/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug\5.0.2\5.0.2\mingw47_32\include\QtWidgets" -I"C:\Qt\5.0.2\5.0.2\mingw47`, have you tried creating a similar function and using it as a public slot?

Comment: Perfect, it is an reference error. I did some testing on my Mac and i noticed that when haven't defined the function in the .cpp while it's declared as a public function you don't seem to get an error. And you get the error when you move it into the public slot. Can you paste the piece of the function stateChanged that you have declared in the .cpp file?

Comment: Code of my function : `void stateChanged(int state)
{
    //Code here
}`

Comment: try adding downloader:: before like this `void downloader::stateChanged(int state) { //Code here }`

Answer (score 0):

Is the unfound path right? In my `Makefile`, I have:

```
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS) -F/Users/enrico/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/clang_64/lib -framework QtWidgets -F/Users/enrico/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/clang_64/qtbase/lib -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework OpenGL -framework AGL
```

What's the error message for `void stateChanged(int state);`?

Comment: For the `void stateChanged(int state);` here is the error message : `Warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Qt//5.1.0/clang_64/qtbase/lib' Error symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

Comment: There aren't other linker output? Please, post what you have in `Compile Output`. Have you tried `CONFIG += x86_64` with
 `CONFIG -= i386`?

Comment: I already post the compile output in my first comment and CONFIG += x86_64 with CONFIG -= i386 didn't change anything

Comment: Have you tried to rename your function (for using it as a public slot)?

Comment: If I changed is name as a public slot, it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Your .h file shall be compiled as a *.moc before linking phase. If your not found symbol is *stateChanged* that's your missing step. When you get into link phase, no QObject slot is found as a symbol and your linker stops processing.

Or it may lack some QT keyworks/macro to be properly declared as a QObject.

Take a look for details in [Qt5 help for moc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/moc.html#diagnostics)